# How to aggregate iOS location data on server?

Tags: ios, location

1. How do I send location data from an iPhone to some webserver?
2. Is a web server the best way to store that data?
3. If so, what kind of server?

EDIT: Since people were getting confused about the question, understandably, I'm really looking for best practices on how to store location data in a web server. I don't know if the server would be SQL or no-SQL, I have very little experience in the way of web servers.

So here's what I do know:

- I know how to get the location of a user.
- I know to use CoreLocation.

My questions:

- How do I send the location data from the application to a server, both SQL and non-SQL?
- On the server side: How to I store that data? I'm familiar with SQL a little bit but all I'm trying to store is GPS coordinates so I'm not sure if a table is the best way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to expand your question it will help others to help you.

However, I suggest you firstly read the iOS Location Awareness Programming Guide - this will tell you how to get the location of the device.

Next, read about REST/web server/web frameworks etc and check out the AFNetworking framework for sending data from iOS to a web server.

Then you need to decide how to store the data: in a SQL/no-SQL database? It really depends on  what you want to do with the data and what, if any, web servers you have access to/experience with.

I'm afraid your question in it's current form simply raises more questions!

Answer (score 0):

1. CoreLocation
2. Ya, guessing you want to do something with it that's not in the app otherwise just use a database.
3. Be lazy use something like parse.com cloud code.(free 1million api request a month)

Not a great question can you give us a context. What are your doing with the location and why do you need it online.

Answer (score 0):

Although this answer doesn't necessarily promote learning how to do backend stuff yourself, there's this amazing service called [Parse](http://parse.com) that handles almost everything for you. It's incredibly awesome and saves a ton of time. Plus it's free for up to 1,000,000 API calls and 1GB of storage. Absolutely perfect for a small-time business/startup.